# Как в twig удалить английские буквы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, twig

Возможно ли в twig удалить английские буквы?

Делаю так:

```
{{ x|replace({'[A-Za-z]':''}) }}
```

Ничего не удаляет. Может проще можно сделать?

Comment: `{{ x|replace('/[A-Za-z]/', '') }}`?

Comment: в описании twig  скобки так :  {{ x|replace({' что меняем': 'на что меняем'}) }} и все работает , а вот регулярное выражение [A-Za-z] не получается вставить

Comment: Поделитесь ссылкой на документацию.

Comment: https://x-twig.ru/filters/replace/

Comment: Не похоже, чтобы эта функция поддерживала регулярные выражения.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let str = "asdfgdfdasds фывф ывфы ds ad sa ";
let res = str.replace(/[A-z]/g,'');
console.log(res);
{{ res|r('js') }}
```

Comment: когда ввожу:  /[A-z]/g    то выдает ошибку . если в кавычки обверну ,то не удаляет английские слова

Comment: @валера какая ошибка?

Comment: Twig_Error_Syntax                                                                                                             A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "operator" of value "/"         
 Хэш-ключ должен быть строкой, числом, имя или выражение, заключенное в скобки (непредвиденная лексема "оператор" значение "/".